# convert mongodb bindata uuid to sql server uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, converters

How to convert MongoDB bindata uuid to sql server uniqueidentifier?

I have { _id: BinData(3,"FOUmkwBNAEyvGcFpJRpJfA==")} in MongoDB(db.version(): 4.4.11)

I can convert it to UUID by the following command:

db.getCollection('mycollection').findOne({ _id: BinData(3,"FOUmkwBNAEyvGcFpJRpJfA==")})._id.hex()

14e52693004d004caf19c169251a497c

The MS SQL service (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server 2012 R2) uniqueidentifier is

9326E514-4D00-4C00-AF19-C169251A497C

Question How to verify the  MongoDB bindata uuid { _id: BinData(3,"FOUmkwBNAEyvGcFpJRpJfA==")} to sql server uniqueidentifier: 9326E514-4D00-4C00-AF19-C169251A497C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL Server Uniqueidentifier doesn't have to follow any of the UUID versions, so any 16 bytes can be converted into a uniqueidentifier.  And you can cast to uniqueidentifier either from char or from binary types, eg:

```
select cast(0x14e52693004d004caf19c169251a497c as uniqueidentifier)
```

outputs

```
9326E514-4D00-4C00-AF19-C169251A497C
```