# Convert SQL Server uniqueidentifier to MongoDB bindata uuid

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, type-conversion

We can convert MongoDB bindata uuid to SQL Server uniqueidentifier by this query:

```
select cast(0x14e52693004d004caf19c169251a497c as uniqueidentifier)
```

outputs

```
9326E514-4D00-4C00-AF19-C169251A497C
```

[convert mongodb bindata uuid to sql server uniqueidentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632327/convert-mongodb-bindata-uuid-to-sql-server-uniqueidentifier)

Can we convert SQL Server uniqueidentifier to MongoDB bindata uuid?

Comment: Just do the opposite; `CONVERT` the `uniqueidentifier` to a 16-byte value (`binary(16)`).

Comment: Hi  @Larnu, The query does not Convert SQL Server uniqueidentifier to MongoDB bindata uuid: Could you check what is wrong ? select cast(0x9326E5144D004C00AF19C169251A497C as binary(16))

Comment: Hi @Dale K Thank for you edit the post. Could you check what is wrong on this query? select cast(0x9326E5144D004C00AF19C169251A497C as binary(16))